# Break in animation.

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uianimation

Hello people in my application I wanted to do an animation.
The animation has 160 frames and I wanted it to last 10 sec and make a loop.

For it created an Array with frames and a UIImageView.

```
UIImageView *animImageView;
...
NSArray *arrayAnim = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image0001"],...,nil];

animImageView.animationImages=arrayAnim;
animImageView.animationDuration=10;
[animImageView startAnimating];
```

this results and get the animation but at the moment I do startAnimating my application is breaked for 7 seconds.
is there any way to avoid this delay?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your images?

Comment: 640x1136 é a dimensão do ecrã de 4 polegadas retina

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly using too much memory. 640 x 1136 x 4bpp = 2908160 bytes of memory per image. For 160 images that's 465 MB of RAM (more than then 3GS even has!)

Without knowing what your animation looks like, I suggest that you try to build the animation dynamically using UIViews and animating the subviews in real time rather than using pre-rendered frames.

Comment: Turning it into a movie and use AVFoundation is another option

Comment: Absolutely, this would be much better in some cases.